# How to persist a complex query string while paging using Html.RouteLink in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a specialized search engine that passes search criteria from the Search page (form) to the Results page via a long and complex query string (37 parameters) in the URL. It must be done this way rather than as a form post because I want to give users the ability to author their own search queries by constructing custom URLs.

I'm handling the paging as a parameter in the URL and not as part of the query string. So for example "/Search/Results?keyword=&..." directs to page 1, and "/Search/Results/6?keyword=&..." directs to page 6, etc. I'm looking for a way to persist the query string across the pages, but I can't seem to find a way for RouteLink to "reattach" the incoming query string to the URL it generates. Some posts I've seen suggest explicitly attaching each parameter as "new { }", but there are 37 of them so that way wouldn't be practical.

What I'd really like to find is something like;

```
Html.RouteLink("Next", "Default", new { controller = "Search", action = "Results", page = nextPage, Request.QueryString });
```

but that doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a good candidate for a custom html helper:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString MyRouteLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string routeName, object routeValues)
    {
        var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext);
        var request = htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Request;
        var url = urlHelper.RouteUrl(routeName, routeValues, request.Url.Scheme);
        var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(url);
        var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);
        foreach (string key in request.QueryString.Keys)
        {
            query[key] = request[key];
        }
        var routeQuery = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uriBuilder.Query);
        foreach (string key in routeQuery)
        {
            query[key] = routeQuery[key];
        }
        uriBuilder.Query = query.ToString();
        var anchor = new TagBuilder("a");
        anchor.Attributes["href"] = uriBuilder.ToString();
        anchor.SetInnerText(linkText);
        return new HtmlString(anchor.ToString());
    }
}
```

which you would use in your view:

```
@Html.MyRouteLink(
    "Next", 
    "Default", 
    new { 
        controller = "Search", 
        action = "Results", 
        page = nextPage
    }
)
```

Comment: This works very well - I love the fact that it automatically ports the query string without my having to pass it as a value. Thanks so much! =^.^=

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
<a href="@Url.RouteUrl(new 
        {
            controller = "Search", 
            action = "Results", 
            page = nextPage
         }
     )?@Request.QueryString">Next</a>
```

Comment: You will end up with multiple `?` in the final url with this. One returned by the RouteUrl helper, and the one you have hardcoded after it.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, even if `page` is a route parameter? What would be the ? and querystring params genereated by the RouteUrl?

Comment: no, if page is a route parameter there won't be a problem. But writing code inside a view that depends on whether something is a route parameter or not seems very fragile. The only place where routes should be handled is the RegisterRoutes method. Everything else should be html/url helpers depending on the configuration that is done inside this method. If someone decides to change the fact that the `page` parameter is no longer a route parameter if you hardcode something like that, you will have to modify all your views to make this effective.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov would you consider it fragile if the route param is backed by a unit test? Asking for my own education here. I personally try to avoid custom helpers, and the Html helper in general as much as possible. To me keeping as much real HTML in the view as possible makes it easier to read, rather than having to decipher helper method args, which often have overload explosion.

Comment: I wonder how you would write a unit test for your view because this is where you have hardcoded the url? Don't avoid custom helpers. Use them as much as possible to avoid ending up with fragile and spaghetti code in your views. Not to mention that custom html helpers can be unit tested in isolation contrary to your view code where it is more complicated. It will no longer be a unit test. It will some sort of an integration test where you will be sending requests to your site and verifying that the response HTML is correct. It's still necessary to do integration tests though.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov thanks. Yes the view would not be unit tested, it would be automated UI / qa / integration tested using WebDriver. I don't try to avoid all helpers, just the Html helper. I would actually prefer a custom Url helper in this case over an Html helper, since all you really need to do is generate the correct URL.

Comment: sure, in this case you could also use an url helper because as you said all we need is the url. But since writing this url logic is the complex part, you could indeed externalize it into a separate url helper and then call it from your custom html helper. Why HTML helper? Because I prefer to write in my view `@Html.MyRouteLink(...)` instead of some tag soup: `<a href="@Url.MyRouteLink(...)">...</a>`. But that's just me. If you prefer this syntax, a url helper is also fine. I am just expressing what I would do when I answer a question on SO and often times it could be subjective.

Answer (score 0):

Create a ActionLink Extension which will add querystring to route values,
like..

```
public static class LinkExtensions
    {
        public static string MyActionLink(this HtmlHelper helper,string actionName,string controllerName,string linkText)
        {
            var qs =helper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString;
            RouteValueDictionary dict=new RouteValueDictionary();
            qs.AllKeys.ToList().ForEach(k=>dict.Add(k,qs[k]));

            UrlHelper urlhelper = new UrlHelper(helper.ViewContext.RequestContext);

            string url = urlhelper.Action(actionName, controllerName, dict);
            TagBuilder tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("a")
            {
                InnerHtml = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(linkText)) ? HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(linkText) : String.Empty
            };
            tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("href", url);
            return tagBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);

        }
    }
```

In the view you can use it as,

@Html.MyActionLink("Index","Home","link to Home")